# Resharper claims expression is always false using LINQ Aggregate with seed

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, aggregate

In the following code Resharper claims that the expression `currMax == null` is always false.

```
public Read Read1
{
    get
    {
        return Reads.Where(read => !read.IsIndex)
                    .Aggregate((Read)null, (currMax, read) => currMax == null || read.Length > currMax.Length ? read : currMax);
    }
}
```

When the first iteration of the lambda expression in the call to `Aggregate`  executes I would expect `currMax == null` to be true since `(Read)null` is the seed. Resharper knows that the upstream `Where` requires non-null `Read` objects in the resulting `IEnumerable` because I am accessing the `IsIndex` property of the `Read` class. Does resharper just not take into account the seed parameter to `Aggregate`?

Edit: I've filed a bug report here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-443055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ReSharper is wrong, judging from the disassembly of `Aggregate` in ILSpy.

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    TAccumulate seed, 
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (func == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("func");
    }
    TAccumulate tAccumulate = seed;
    foreach (TSource current in source)
    {
        tAccumulate = func(tAccumulate, current);
    }
    return tAccumulate;
}
```

Clearly removing the `null` check will result in a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug in ReSharper's nullability analysis. Could you report it to [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP)?

In the meantime you can suppress this warning with `// ReSharper disable once ConditionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse`.